# Remotely turn ON Raspberry Pi 4 without Ethernet

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I'm new to using the Raspberry Pi 4, and every time I want to turn my Pi on through remote desktop, I have to connect my ethernet cable to it so it turns on. The problem is that my ethernet is away from my computer.

How can I turn on the raspberry pi through remote desktop without an ethernet cable, even though I connected it to the WiFi?